# Does this normalization of a positive definite matrix alter its positive definiteness?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a matrix $A$ that is positive definite. Denoting the elements of $A$ by $a_{ij}$, let $A'$ be a new matrix formed as:

$$A'_{ij} = \frac{a_{ij}}{\sqrt{a_{ii}a_{jj}}}$$

Is $A'$ also positive definite? Note: All diagonal elements of $A$ are positive.

Backstory: This situation arises in certain covariance matrix normalizations and several domain specific algorithms in my field require the input to be a PD matrix, but scripts used in our lab do not check for PDness and continue as if they were (they work correctly for PD though). Since I'm using $A'$ instead of $A$, I'd like to know if the PDness can change so that I can interpret the output of the scripts cautiousy (the PDness didn't change for a few sample tests I tried, but that isn't convincing proof).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is. We have $A'=D^\ast AD$ where $D=\operatorname{diag}\left(\frac1{\sqrt{a_{11}}},\ldots,\frac1{\sqrt{a_{nn}}}\right)$. Since $A$ is positive definite and $D$ is invertible, $A'$ is positive definite (for any $x\neq0$, we have $Dx\neq0$ and hence $x^\ast A'x=(Dx)^\ast A(Dx)>0$).