# Scaling of eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose $A_N$ is a positive definite matrix of size $N$ with eigenvalues $\Lambda=\{\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_N\}$. Let $D = \text{diag}\{d_1,\ldots,d_N\},\ d_i>0$ be a diagonal matrix. Can the eigenvalues of $A'_N=DAD$ be written in terms of $\Lambda$ and $d_i$?

Comment: P.S. The above is related to [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/434960/84825). I'm trying to further understand how to proceed analytically (instead of numerically, which is what I'm doing now).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Unfortunately) No, the eigenvalues of $A_N'$ will also depend on the eigenvectors of $A_N$.